# Ununlocking a locked account in membership asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, unlock

I have forgot to change "maxInvalidPasswordAttempts" in my web config and it was on 5! 
Now one of my users get locked. I have change Islocked column to false but it is keeping unlock. Can any body help me how to unlock this user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UnlockUser()` method in your code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.unlockuser.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You want to update in two columns in Membership table.

IsLockedOut to 0

FailedPasswordAttemptCount to 0